# Where to place font awesome folder 'font' in wordpress theme directory?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, font-awesome

Hey everyone I want to add font awesome in my word press theme manually I have already linked fontawesome css and placed the font folder in

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen
```

But font awesome is not applying?

Comment: did you get any error in the console?

Comment: did you set the font awesome CSS path in header?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Yes I did set it in functions.php file in function twentysixteen_scripts().

Comment: can you paste here the path you have given into functions.php

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj                                                                                             wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');

Comment: now open your styles.css and  change font family with your font properties.

Comment: exactly same like below answer by @roopa  font-family: 'fontawesome';

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Followed all the steps but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141617/discussion-between-raj-kumar-bhardwaj-and-phpnoob).

Answer (score 2):

To better response.

Please visit http://fontawesome.io/ official site and download font awesome folder.[I am attaching a image to proper understand. Please check the attachment][1].  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NCHz.png

Now take all fonts file and put in your theme fonts folder.
and use @font face to add in css like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fontawesome';
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

Also take css font-awesome.min.css library and put in your theme css folder and attach in functions.php or header.php in a head section.

I hope it will helpfull for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add this rule,

```
fa fas{ font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important; 
    font-size:16px !important; 
}
```